# How do I install libudev with cmake

Tags: cmake, udev

I have a binary (c++) and I want to link against the libudev library. But I want my cmake file verified if the udev library it's installed. If not, download the package and install it. But the only away to install udev library (I think) it's by using `sudo apt-get install libudev-dev` package or something like that.

My question is: is possible, using a cmake file, download the libudev-dev package ?

Comment: In CMake you may use [execute_process](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/execute_process.html) for execute arbitrary shell command. Does this resolve your problem?

Comment: It's seems working. But it's possible to install a package without sudo permission? Or install in a different directory that doesn't need sudo access?

Comment: Package manager (`apt` in your case) installs packages into *system directories*, thus requires root permissions. For install the library into other place, you need to download *sources* of that library, build them (for new install directory) and install them.

Comment: Yeah. In this case, I want to install libudev with cmake. I doesn't get the official repository from udev. I have some modules that download libraries, build and install it. But to udev library, I doesn't get to do it. To try solving it, I've imagined to install the package. But now, it's make sense that I need root access.  Do you have some tips to solve it?

Comment: Solve what? Installing with `apt` **requires** root privileges, you cannot overcome that. If you search for `libudev` sources, [see that question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31983/where-is-the-official-udev-source-and-other-dev-information).

Comment: Ok, thanks. My problem it's to install libudev library with cmake.  The makefile on this repository that you indicated, has include many other libraries. And I want only install the udev library. And I don't know how to achieve it.

Comment: It is unlikely that you can **build** `udev` separately from the whole `systemd`. But in any case, it is an **another question** and has nothing common with CMake.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have a binary thas has dependency from udev. And to get my binary, I use cmake to cross-compiler. And in this case, if the udev it's not found, I must to download, build and install it. That's why I use cmake.

Comment: Better to have libudev as a **prerequisite** for your project. So it is user who should obtain (and install) libudev before building your project. No needs to make your project completely standalone.